# Why is the time identical for Cython and Python versions of function?

Tags: cython

I am just starting out learning about Cython. I have some code written in pure Python, and started to convert it to Cython. The first function is below (both versions). I expected Cython to be faster, but there is no difference in speed. Why is this? Am I doing something wrong, or is it expected?

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import time

ctypedef np.int8_t DTYPE_int

cpdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_int, ndim=2] init_population(int N, int pop_size):
    
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_int, ndim=2] p
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_int, ndim=2] idx
    cdef double t1

    t1=time.time()
    p = np.full((pop_size, N), np.arange(N, dtype=np.int8))
    idx = np.random.rand(p.shape[0], p.shape[1]).argsort(axis=1).astype(np.int8)
    print("%.20f" % (time.time() - t1))
    return np.take_along_axis(p, idx, axis=1)

def py_init_population(N, pop_size):
    t1=time.time()
    p = np.full((pop_size, N), np.arange(N, dtype=np.int8))
    idx = np.random.rand(p.shape[0], p.shape[1]).argsort(axis=1).astype(np.int8)
    print("%.20f" % (time.time() - t1))
    return np.take_along_axis(p, idx, axis=1)

init_population(1000, 1000)
py_init_population(1000, 1000)
```

Output:
7.24499845504760742188
7.26293945312500000000

Comment: I can't find a good duplicate right now (but I'm sure there is one because this basic question gets asked a lot). The gist is that all the work is inside the Numpy functions rather than in your code, which are already mostly written in optimized C. Cython's good at optimizing things like loops over Numpy arrays (which are slow in Python) but makes no difference to the speed that the Numpy internals operate at.

Comment: @DavidW I had thought as much, but wanted to check. If you put this as answer I will accept.